# Can we run games like plants vs. zombie on ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: games, android

I have researched options like Android studio and Chrome Altered version but none of the is helpful. While installing Studio,I can practically run but could get much as it required some repository from google which where either blocked or unavailable. Where as the latter crashes when I run Plant vs. Zombie app.
[image: When I ran the Cmd "./android"] [image: This window pops up with the msg]
***Need a little help,I am New to Ubuntu/Linux.***

Comment: So that the community can better help you solve your problem, please include how you're trying to run your apps, whether it be through the native linux system, an emulator, or any other means.

Comment: I installed Chrome with ARC welder Extension and Android Studio by it's package provided by Google. Installed Java Runtime 8 and Eclipse from S/W centre for support.
1)Android Studio, I launched it through the terminal (./android) but it lacks some packages and repository which were not downloadable from the site.
2)Chrome in developer mode with Arc welder, I needed apk File of the app. So, I downloaded the app and Used ES File Explorer to make a back up of the app. Ran  .apk file with the ARC extn . It ran successfully but need access to Play store to add some more data but was unable to do.